# Unable to fix / by zero error in Java

Tags: java

I have tried to fix this every way I know how but i have no clue at this point, and my professor is a total tool who will belittle you if you even ask for help, do please help. This is one of the projects I am required to do to pass the class.

```
public class Student {
    private String name;           //name of the student
    private String id;             //student id
    private String major;          //student’s major: CSCI,MATH,NURS, all others are XXXX
    private int    completedHours; //number of hours the student has completed
    private int    qualityPoints;  //number of overall quality points a student has completed
    private char   studentType;    //type of student G (graduate) U (undergraduate) X (invalid type)

    public Student() {

    }

    public Student(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }//end Student()

    public Student(String name, String id, String major, char studentType) {
        setName(name);
        setId(id);
        setMajor(major);
        setStudentType(studentType);
    }//end Student(String,String,String,char)

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.name = name;
    } //end setName(String)

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }//end setId(String)

    public void setMajor(String major) {
        this.major = major;
    }//end setMajor(String)

    public void setCompletedHours(int hours) {
    hours = completedHours;
    }//end setCompletedHours(int)

    public void setQualityPoints(int points) {
        points = qualityPoints;
    }//end setQualityPoints(int)

    public void setStudentType(char type) {
        if (type == 'u' && type == 'U')
            type = 'U';
        else if (type == 'g' && type == 'G')
            type = 'G';
        else 
            type = 'X';

        type = studentType;
    }//end setStudentType(char)

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }//end getStudentName()

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }//end getId()

    public String getMajor() {
        return major;
    }//end getMajor()

    public int getCompletedHours() {
        return completedHours;
    }//end getCompletedHours()

    public int getQualityPoints() {
        return qualityPoints;
    }//end getQualityPoints()

    public char getStudentType() {
        return studentType;
    }//end 

    public double gpa() {
        double gpa;

        gpa = qualityPoints / completedHours;

        return gpa;
    }

    public void addCompletedHours(int hours) {
        if ( hours<0) {
            completedHours = completedHours;
        } else {
            if (hours >=0)
                completedHours += hours;
        }
    }

    public String classification() {
        String strClassification;
        strClassification = "A";

        if (studentType == 'G')
            strClassification = "Graduate";
        else if (studentType == 'X')
            strClassification = "Invalid Student Type";
        else if (completedHours<30)
            strClassification = "Freshman";
        else if (completedHours<60)
            strClassification = "Sophomore";
        else if (completedHours<90)
            strClassification = "Junior";
        else if (completedHours>90)
            strClassification = "Senior";

        return strClassification;
    }

    public String studentRecord() {
        String  strStudentRecord;
        strStudentRecord = ("\n Name:\t\t" + name + "\n ID:\t\t\t"  + id + "\nMajor:\t\t" + major + "\nCompletedHrs: " + completedHours + "\nQuality Pts:\t" + qualityPoints + "\nGPA:\t\t\t" + gpa() + "\nClassification:   " + classification());

        return strStudentRecord;
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
Execption in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticEcxeption: / by zero
at Student.gpa(Student.java:105)
at Student.studentRecord(Student.java:164)
at Project3.main(Project3.java:11)
```

Class Project3:

```
public class Project3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strStudent1;

        Student stu1 = new Student("John Smith", "1234B", "Nursing", 'U');
        stu1.setCompletedHours(34);
        stu1.setQualityPoints(85);

        strStudent1 = stu1.studentRecord();

        System.out.print(strStudent1);
    }//end main
}//end Project3
```

Comment: How is `completedHours` defined?  Can you provide the entire `stu1` class?

Comment: paste enough code so we can understand the flow

Comment: Could you provide more code ? What is "stu1" ?

Comment: Step one: stop dividing by zero. Seriously: we have no idea what those setters actually do. Hint two: `gpa` is a one-liner.

Comment: I edited and added all of my code, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setters are wrong.

This:

```
public void setCompletedHours(int hours)
{
    hours = completedHours;
}//end setCompletedHours(int)

public void setQualityPoints(int points)
{
    points = qualityPoints;

}//end setQualityPoints(int)
```

should be this:

```
public void setCompletedHours(int hours)
{
    completedHours = hours;
}//end setCompletedHours(int)

public void setQualityPoints(int points)
{
    qualityPoints = points;

}//end setQualityPoints(int)
```

You aren't setting anything in your setters. So, both `qualityPoints` and `completedHours`  are zero.

Then, when you call `gpa()` it tries to divide by zero.
Btw, try debugging it next time and you should see your values.

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate it. I'm completely new to most of this so this was a big help